# What does ‘‪いてね‬’ mean?

Tags: grammar, meaning

What does ‪いてね‬ mean in ‘‪聴いてね‬’?

Comment: What do you understand 聴 to be?

Answer (score 1):

The verb of the sentence is 聴く{きく}, that means "to listen". The いて is the desinence of the て conjugation, that is used for connecting, as a gerund, and as an imperative (like in this case).

ね is a "gobi" (a particle you put at the end of a sentence to give a nuance to it). In this case, it makes the imperative softer.

So, in this case, いてね is nothing by itself, the sentence 聴いてね{きいてね} is something like "listen, please".

Answer (score 0):

You are not parsing this correctly.

聴く is the base form of the verb here. We are looking at a conjugation to the て-form of the verb (聴いて) followed by the sentence ending particle ね.